# WPF DirectortInfo hang the system when many files inside folder is selected

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, delegates, openfiledialog

Hi Stackoverflow Family,
I am doing one simple WPF project where I have to select the folder. The issue here is when I select a folder with less than 20-30 files, it works well. But when file count is more than 80+ and user select that folder system hangs for few second.
Anyone know a better approach please suggest.
Code :

```
private void uploadFile()
{
if(fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
  folderName = fileDialog.SelectedPath;
  DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folderName);
  FileInfo[] info = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.*");
   FileListBox.ItemsSource = info;
 }
}
```

Note: Any concept which helps to show waiting dialog until file upload finish, is also ok for me

Comment: What do you think you could do? What have you tried yourself?

Comment: I tried to use this.Dispatcher.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate{ // file upload });

Comment: How does this code actually upload the file?

Comment: user will select folder path and we will check the dirInfor.getfile() to get all file inside folder, then display it to listbox, after that I have another code which do something/ but issue is till this point only process take a lot of time

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]?